# How can I use a non-static (dynamic instance) object as return for a static method in Java?

Tags: java, static, return

I have searched through stackoverflow as well as a few other sites and sadly have not found this question asked, let alone answered.  Maybe my approach is best attempted another way?  I am new to Java; this should be a really easy answer I would think.

**The issue:** 
I have a ***static*** method that I would like to return values from.  For convenience and neatness I would like to use my own class instead of an *ArrayList*, *String[]*, or similar.  Problem is that I cannot instantiate my class within the static method (as I expected could be an issue).  Funny thing though: using *String[]* or *Object* as the return does work (which is an instance of those classes)... so why can't I use my own class instance?

**Example:**

```
public static String[] decodeText(String codeString) {
    //Parse codestring and return values (not included in this example)
    String[] data = new String[3];
    data[0]="This";
    data[1]="does";
    data[2]="work";                
    return data;
}
```

The above works great but when I use my own class to return values the compiler gives me the "non-static variable *this* cannot be referenced from a static context" **(NOTE: edited to show that these classes are nested within the JInputs class which apparently is necessary to reproduce the error):**

```
public class JInputs extends JOptionPane {    
    //A lot of missing code here (which shouldn't be necessary to reproduce issue)

    public class UserData {
        public String userName;
        public String code;
        public long milliTime;

        UserData() {            
        }
        UserData(String userName, String code, long milliTime) {
            this.userName = userName;
            this.milliTime = milliTime;
            this.code = code;
        }
    }

    public static UserData decodeText(String codeString) {
        //Parse codestring and return values (not included in this example)
        UserData data = new UserData();
        data.milliTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        data.code = "blah";
        data.userName = "Me";                
        return data;
    }
}
```

Obviously, I could make my *UserData* class a static class but then wouldn't subsequent calls to the method change the values of the original call?  How do Java programmers return neat data from static methods?  Why does it allow built-in classes to be instantiated but not user defined classes?

Comment: Please take a look at the edited question -- the error should be reproduce-able now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the error you have, your question probably misses a bit of code, it is probably like:

```
public class SomeClass {
      public class UserData {
            ....
      }

      public static UserData decodeText(String codeString) {
            UserData data = new UserData();
            ....
      }
}
```

## Inner Classes

So you are using the concept of Inner Classes. Those classes need to have access to an instance of their parent class to be created (here UserData would need to have access to an instance of SomeClass). This access is provided by the JVM when the inner class is created from within a non-static method via the "this" pointer. However, one does not have access to "this" in a static method: this is what the compiler is telling you: UserData cannot be created because it needs to have access to this ("non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context").

But you could create a new instance of UserData in any non-static method of SomeClass or UserData and any of their subclasses.

## Your Use Case

In your case, you do not seem to need an inner class. You only need a nested class when you want to have access to the members of the parent class. Otherwise a static nested class is enough.

### Your Question

> I could make my UserData class a static class but then wouldn't subsequent calls to the method change the values of the original call?

No the subsequent callq to the method wouldn't change the value of instances created by previous call to the method. A static class does not mean that its variables are static, or that it is a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). A static class is basically like a standard class, only it is nested within another classes definition.
For more information on the difference between static and non-static nested classes see the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) on this.

Comment: Thank you!  You've helped provide the conceptual information that I was needing.  For my education, I also fixed the issue by making UserData a class of it's own instead of a nested class.
So what is the best approach for small classes meant simply for returning values from a method?  Create a class for each or perhaps make a "ReturnValues" class that has several static nested classes? Or include them in the class that has the method that uses it most?  Probably the latter but that might be a preference question.

Comment: @DatuPuti It makes sense to have a static class when this class is only going to be instantiated inside the parent class, and only makes sense within the context of its parent. For example Map.Entry (and it's vanilla implementation HashMap.Node), doesn't make sense outside of the context of a Map, an nobody will create any outside of it.

Answer (score 6):

The only problem this code has is a misplaced curly bracket:

```
public class UserData {
    public String userName;
    public String code;
    public long milliTime;

    UserData() {            
    }
    UserData(String userName, String code, long milliTime) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.milliTime = milliTime;
        this.code = code;
    }
} //end of class!

//this method is outside the class!
public static UserData decodeText(String codeString) {
    //Parse codestring and return values (not included in this example)
    UserData data = new UserData();
    data.milliTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    data.code = "blah";
    data.userName = "Me";                
    return data;
}
```

I imagine what you want instead is this:

```
public class UserData {
    public String userName;
    public String code;
    public long milliTime;

    UserData() {            
    }
    UserData(String userName, String code, long milliTime) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.milliTime = milliTime;
        this.code = code;
    }


    public static UserData decodeText(String codeString) {
        //Parse codestring and return values (not included in this example)
        UserData data = new UserData();
        data.milliTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        data.code = "blah";
        data.userName = "Me";                
        return data;
    }
}
```

> The above works great but when I use my own class to return values the compiler gives me the "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context"

The code you posted does not result in that error. You either copied the code wrong, or you're looking at an old error.

> Obviously, I could make my UserData class a static class but then wouldn't subsequent calls to the method change the values of the original call?

There really isn't a concept of "static class" the way you're describing. A static class is simply an inner class that can be accessed without an instance of the outer class. All of its members still act like the members of a normal class.

> How do Java programmers return neat data from static methods? Why does it allow built-in classes to be instantiated but not user defined classes?

What you posted would work fine. Java does not make a distinction between "built-in" classes and "user-defined" classes.

Comment: Interesting...  No, I did intend the class to be simply a container for data -- the decodeText method is part of a different class and only related in that it returns data of the UserData type.  Will this allow outside classes to reference and use the UserData class (if kept public)?  Though not what I was expecting, this may be the best way to accomplish what I want?  Thanks for your response!!

Comment: @DatuPuti You can copy that entire decodeText() function into another class and it would work fine. The code you posted does not generate the error you're describing.

Comment: Hmmm... it still does for me.  Probably I didn't give you enough information in that this is all included within the base class as follows: 
public class JInputs extends JOptionPane {    
    public class UserData {
    ///etc....
    }
}

Comment: @DuPuti I would bet that something got lost in the copy-paste step. The code you posted works fine for me, either the way I posted it or in a different class. I suspect that your actual code contains an error that the code you posted does not- you fixed your own error in the copying process!

Comment: It must be something to do with the base class because I still get the same error when I copy it back... regardless, you've helped me to understand that using the static keyword in this context will not cause problems with subsequent calls to the method (that is correct right?).  So I'll just make it static.  Thanks again!

Comment: @DatuPuti If the `UserData` class is inside of another class and you want to use it this way you should mark it `static` like this : `public static class UserData { ... }`. Otherwise inner classes that aren't static expect to have a reference to the enclosing class at all times.